# Convert array of objects as string into array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

from this

```
["{\r\n  \"charge_type\": \"sports\",\r\n  \"amount\": 1000\r\n},{\r\n  \"charge_type\": \"servicing\",\r\n  \"amount\": 550\r\n}"]
```

to this

```
[{"charge_type"=>"sports", "amount"=> "1000"},{"charge_type"=>"servicing", "amount"=> "500"}]
```

I have tried this,

```
JSON.parse(["{\r\n  \"charge_type\": \"sports\",\r\n  \"amount\": 1000\r\n},{\r\n  \"charge_type\": \"servicing\",\r\n  \"amount\": 550\r\n}"].first)
```

But could not figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that has been unmaintained for many years and has open, unpatched security vulnerabilities?

Comment: That's because it's not valid JSON. Check it with a [linter](https://jsonlint.com). Hint: Surround it with `[ ... ]`. For some reason you've done that *external* to the JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problem because your json is not valid, your array `[]` is not wrapped around string, it need to be `"[]"` then it will work.

e.g your current json will give error

```
unexpected token at ',{
  "charge_type": "servicing",
  "amount": 550
```

but if your json is completely wrapped inside string like this (notice `"` around array)

```
my_json = "[{\r\n  \"charge_type\": \"sports\",\r\n  \"amount\": 1000\r\n},{\r\n  \"charge_type\": \"servicing\",\r\n  \"amount\": 550\r\n}]"
```

then you can do something like this

```
JSON.parse(my_json)
```

which will return

```
[{"charge_type"=>"sports", "amount"=>1000}, {"charge_type"=>"servicing", "amount"=>550}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do with the `[...].first` part. What you really need is:

```
JSON.parse("[{\r\n  \"charge_type\": \"sports\",\r\n  \"amount\": 1000\r\n},{\r\n  \"charge_type\": \"servicing\",\r\n  \"amount\": 550\r\n}]")
```